# Multiple controls to servo on standard i/o port (ATmega32 AVR)?

Tags: embedded, avr, atmega

I'm basically trying to perform a **chain** of actions on multiple servo motors when a particular button is pressed.The following code works fine but can only perform a single movement on multiple servos i.e when the button is pressed Servo1 moves to 900 and servo2 to 1500 else they go back to standard positions.

What I want to achieve is a set of movements, for instance when the button is pressed I want both the servos to swing(0 to 180 to 0(3 different movements)). I tried to use a delay function and change the values of the servo but then it wouldn't work, which im assuming is because the delay becomes greater than my Fast PWM time period.

```
void main()
{
DDRB = 0xFF;
DDRC = 0x00;
PORTC = 0XFF;

TCCR1A |= 1<<WGM11;
TCCR1B |= 1<<WGM12 | 1<<WGM13 | 1<<CS10;
TIMSK  |= 1<<OCIE1A;

ICR1=19999; 

sei();

uint16_t Servo1 = 2000, Servo2 = 900;

while(1)
{
    if(bit_is_clear(PINC,0)) 
  {
      Servo1 = 900, Servo2 = 1500;
     }
 else{
     Servo1 = 1500, Servo2=2200;
 }
  if(TCNT1>=800 && TCNT1<=2400)
  {
       if (TCNT1 >= Servo1 && bit_is_set(PORTB,PINB0)) PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB0);
       if (TCNT1 >= Servo2 && bit_is_set(PORTB,PINB1)) PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB1); 
  } 

}
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
 PORTB = 0xFF;  
}
```

How do I go about the same?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: If possible, I'd pick a MCU with hardware PWM. Maybe your timer hardware even supports it. At the very least you should have an output compare feature, which allows the toggling of a pin when the timer elapses. In that case, the only software involved will be resetting the timer and your CPU can do other things in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are implementing your PWM manually using the Timer1, that means that you can't add delays as those from <util/delay.h> so, your only option is implement something similar to a state machine.

define a variable for the state where STATE0 will be the waiting state, STATE1 will be the first movement STATE2 the second movement and so on...

then define a 'time table' to define how much time it'll wait on each state, (ideally it should be a condition table but anyway...)

```
enum{ STATE0,STATE1,STATE2};// from 0 to 2
int time[3]={0,500,500}; //for state 0 it'll wait the button
volatile int time_counter=0; //needs to be volatile 'cos it's used inside the interrupt
int state = STATE0;

void main()
{
DDRB = 0xFF;
DDRC = 0x00;
PORTC = 0XFF;

TCCR1A |= 1<<WGM11;
TCCR1B |= 1<<WGM12 | 1<<WGM13 | 1<<CS10;
TIMSK  |= 1<<OCIE1A;

ICR1=19999; 

sei();

uint16_t Servo1 = 2000, Servo2 = 900; // are these initial values ok for STATE0?

while(1)
{
    //eval state
    switch(state){
        case STATE0:
            if(bit_is_clear(PINC,0)) // if button
            {
                //change state
                state=STATE1;
                time_counter=0;
                //do task
                Servo1 = 900, Servo2 = 1500;
            }
        break;
        case STATE1:
            if(time_counter>time[state])
            {
                //change state
                state=STATE2;
                time_counter=0;
                //do task
                Servo1 = 1500, Servo2 = 2200;
            }
        break;
        case STATE2:
            if(time_counter>time[state])
            {
                //change state
                state=STATE0; // go to wait the buton again
                time_counter=0; // not necesary but anyway...
                //do task
                Servo1 = 2000, Servo2 = 900;
            }

        break;
    }
    //do the pwm stuff
    if(TCNT1>=800 && TCNT1<=2400)
  {
       if (TCNT1 >= Servo1 && bit_is_set(PORTB,PINB0)) PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB0);
       if (TCNT1 >= Servo2 && bit_is_set(PORTB,PINB1)) PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB1); 
  } 

}
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
 PORTB = 0xFF;  
 time_counter++; //here we count the pwm cycles...
}
```

I haven't check your timer configuration, hence I actually don't know if the waiting time of 500 cycles should be enough or too much, but you should change the time[] table according your tests...

it's also recommended to use 2 switches, one to check the condition and change the states accordingly, and the other one to actually do the task for the actual state... I just got lazy and did both in a single switch...

also as you are using an enum{}, it's better that you rename the states to soemthing meaningful, like STATE_WAIT or STATE_POS_180 or STATE_LOCATION_A...